# What's the equivalent of Oracle's to_char in AS400 DB2 SQL syntax?

Tags: oracle, db2, ibm-midrange, to-char

I'm trying to display a DATE field fetched from a DB2 instance.

In Oracle I'd use something like:

```
to_char(v_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD')
```

What's the equivalent in **AS400 DB2**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In V5R3 or later, use the CHAR() function.  To get the same results as your Oracle example, use this:

```
char(v_date, ISO)
```

When using the CHAR() function with date fields, you can choose from the following formats: ISO, USA, EUR, JIS, and local.  When using "local" as the format, it will use the attributes of the ODBC connection job, which will probably be the system-level values of date format and date separator.  The other date formats are as such:

```
ISO = 'yyyy-mm-dd'
USA = 'mm/dd/yyyy'
EUR = 'dd.mm.yyyy'
JIS = 'yyyy-mm-dd'
```

In V5R4, you can use the varchar_format function.  The only valid formats for this function are 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS' and 'YYYY-MM-DD'.

In V6R1 you have better formatting options for the varchar_format function.  As mentioned in another answer, to_char is an alternative to varchar_format.

Answer (score 1):

This should help:

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/db2/library/techarticle/0211yip/0211yip3.html

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that the DB2 equivalent to "`to_char`" is... "`to_char`".

```
:)
```

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9/topic/com.ibm.db2.udb.admin.doc/doc/r0007108.htm

The underlying function is `varchar_format`, for which `to_char` is a synonym.

Comment: I edited my answer to include to_char.  My office is a bit behind in OS releases, so I only get V5R3 to play with.  Varchar_format (and it's synonym to_char) were added in V5R4 with expanded capabilities in V6R1.